# Cannot import HUnit into ghci

Tags: haskell, ghci, hunit

I've just installed HUnit, and want to import it into ghci.

```
Prelude> import HUnit

<no location info>:
    Could not find module `HUnit':
      Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

Also, I'm not sure how to use the `-v` to help me.

```
Prelude> import -v HUnit

<interactive>:1:8: parse error on input `-'

Prelude> import -v

<interactive>:1:8: parse error on input `-'

Prelude> -v

<interactive>:1:2: Not in scope: `v'
```

How can I import it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The correct module is `Test.HUnit`. Import that and it should work.

To use the `-v` option, either specify it on the command line, e.g. `ghci -v`, or type `:set -v` from within GHCi.

Comment: Are there even any up-to-date documentation for HUnit? The "official" at sourceforge seems to be really out-of-date.

Comment: @rzetterberg: Try [the API docs on Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HUnit/latest/doc/html/Test-HUnit.html).